# Having trouble with the shell method

Tags: integration

I actually can't even picture what this would look like or how to set this function up. Can anyone help get me started/ set up? Here's the problem:

*Let $T$ be a triangle, $1 \le x \le 2, 0 \le y \le 3x-3$. 
Find the volume by rotation T around the line 
$$y = -1$$*

Comment: The very first thing to do is to get an idea of what things look like in the $xy$-plane. Have you drawn a sketch of the information in the problem?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not sure how to draw an inequality like that

Comment: x @MathHard: Can you draw the boundary lines $1=x$, $x=2$, $0=y$ and $y=3x-3$, and figure out which parts of your drawing are on the right side of all of them?

Comment: @HenningMakholm ahh, ok, I've got my triangle drawn. What's next?

Comment: x @MathHard: Cross-hatch it with little lines parallel to the axis of revolution (which you've drawn too, right?) Each of those little lines become a cylindrical shell of volume $2\pi$ times the distance from the line to the axis, times length of the line, times the distance between the crosshatch lines. Write down the sum of these volumes, and let the distance go to 0 so the sum becomes an integral.

Answer (score 0):

A typical line segment parallel to the axis of revolution is horizontal, so it corresponds to a y-value.

The distance from the line segment to $y=-1$ is given by $y+1$,

and its length is given by $x_1-x_2=2-\frac{y+3}{3}=\frac{3-y}{3}$;

so $V=\displaystyle\int_0^32\pi r(y)h(y)\;dy=\int_0^32\pi(y+1)\left(\frac{3-y}{3}\right)\;dy$.